# add padding in heading tag through jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i have simple html within it i have one parent div and its have 3 child div, every child contains a same headinig tag "h3" i want to add 10px padding in h3 tag excluding first tag without interact with html. for example first h3= padding top=0; second h3= padding top=10px; third h3= padding top=20px;

```
<style>

.main { width:980px; margin:0 auto; border:solid 1px #F00; overflow:hidden}

.box { width:300px; float:left; margin-right:20px; background:#00F; height:200px;}


</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    //code

    })

</script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="main">
<div class="box"><h3>first</h3></div>
<div class="box"><h3 style="padding-top:10px;">second</h3></div>
<div class="box"><h3 style="padding-top:20px;">third</h3></div>

</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selectors:

```
$('.main h3:not(:first)').css('paddingTop', '10px');​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/f3fmC/

If there are other `<h3>`s in `.main` and you're only interested in those inside `.box`, then adjust the selector:

```
$('.main .box:not(:first) h3').css('paddingTop', '10px');​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/DYTmL/

And if you want to use an increasing `padding-top`, iterate through the `<h3>`s with [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$('.main h3:not(:first)').each(function(i) {
    $(this).css('paddingTop', (i + 1) * 10);
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/QuyWj/

Or simpler:

```
$('.main h3').each(function(i) {
    $(this).css('paddingTop', i * 10);
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/YAYJw/

Comment: your ans is very close to solve my problem, it is not add padding in first h3 as we use .not method of jquery but i want to add pading in next h3 10px and next to second h3 is 20px and if i have one more than 30px to that

Comment: @amit: Ah, I did't notice the increasing padding. Check my update please.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".box h3").not(":first").css("paddingTop","10px");
});
```

Do you mean:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var paddingTop = 10;
    $(".box h3").not(":first").each(function() {
        $(this).css("paddingTop",paddingTop+"px");
        paddingTop +=10;
    });
});
```

Comment: your ans is very close to solve my problem, it is not add padding in first h3 as we use .not method of jquery but i want to add pading in next h3 10px and next to second h3 is 20px and if i have one more than 30px to that

Comment: see the added answer, did you mean something like that..?

Answer (score 0):

Use css [:nth-child pseudo class](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Test/CSS3/Selectors/current/html/full/flat/css3-modsel-28b.html)!

Comment: jquery has nth-child selector too http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/ may be it works? I dont know, sorry, i dont have ie